# How To Display a random row from database on button click?

Tags: javascript, php, css, bootstrap-4

I'm a beginner, and I want to know how to display a random row from database On `BootstrapButton` Click.

here's my code:

```
<h3 id="myHeader">Press the button below to display a name</h3>

        <script>
    function displayResult() {
        document.getElementById("myHeader").innerHTML =<?php $row["Name"] ?>;
    }
    </script>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="displayResult()">Another One</button>
```

Comment: You need to use AJAX for it

Comment: Here is a [simple tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp)

Comment: You can't use `PHP` inside a `<script>` tag! You need to use [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to create a PHP page which fetches a random item from a table and outputs the result

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

Then, on button click, you want to create an Ajax request to the page and display the results. I would use [JQuery](https://jquery.com/) for this

```
$.ajax({
    url: "random.php",
    success: function(response){
        $('#myHeader').html(response);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to do a php script and fetch that row , and use ajax to get that response

```
$.ajax({
    url: "path_to_your_file",
    success: //your_Logic
  })
```

Now you have send a request after opening your php script and wait for the response.

```
var your_request= new XMLHttpRequest();
your_request.open("GET","your_file.php="data_var_name_in_php="+data ...);
your_request.send();
your_request.onreadystatechange = function result() {
  document.getElementById("myHeader").innerHTML = your_request.responseText;
}
```

I advise you to test your php script first to check what you can get as a response text on your local server.
See Ajax Documentation for more information : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: what about the button? what code should I put in it?

Comment: put the code example I just gave in your display_result Function , then trigger it with .click and not onClick as Jquery supports ".click" handler. Don't Forget to add the script link for jquery. Keep me notified.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to your database MySQL via JS using this library :
http://www.mysqljs.com/

and this is the code to connect :

```
MySql.Execute(
"mysql.yourhost.com", 
"username", 
"password", 
"database", 
"select * from Users", 
function (data) {
    console.log(data)
});
```